# Largest index where condition is true, without using argwhere

Tags: numpy

I want to get the largest index where a condition is true, e.g.:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10, 0, -1)
i = np.max(np.argwhere(a > 5).ravel())
print(i)
```

which gives `4`.

But I want to do this on a very large array, where `np.argwhere` is simply too costly.

**How can I do this without allocating a (large) array, i.e. without `np.argwhere`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `argmax` on flipped mask that gives us first index and thus essentially last index in original order -

```
len(a)-np.argmax((a>5)[::-1])-1
```